# Жил как-то мужчина по имени Хитрюга(,) — хотя, быть может, это была женщина

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

> Жил как-то на свете мужчина по имени Хитрюга — хотя, быть может, это была женщина, ибо в истории об этом умалчивается.

У [Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=196) есть пункт о союзе "но":

> Рассмотрим пример: *Он размахнулся и изо всех сил ударил мать по лицу (?) но ему был только один год* — здесь одной запятой перед союзом *но* было бы недостаточно для выражения усиленного противопоставления, а потому на месте вопросительного знака могло бы быть или многоточие (для выражения неожиданности, способной вызвать улыбку), или запятая и тире.

Мне кажется, пример выше подходит под это описание. Можно ли в нем поставить запятую перед тире? Источник примера не очень надежный в плане пунктуации, могут быть ошибки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Жил как-то на свете мужчина по имени Хитрюга — хотя, быть может, это была женщина, ибо в истории об этом умалчивается.

Я не вижу здесь усиленного противопоставления, здесь сомнение в истинности утверждения. Пауза здесь большая, поэтому тире на месте, можно и многоточие, и скобки. Конструкция похожа на присоединение: сказал, подумал и добавил ещё один вариант. Но вот запятую мне здесь ставить не хочется, по-моему, причин для её постановки нет.